# How to create "DecodeAuthorizationMessage" log in cloudtrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I manually reproduce this API log's in cloudtrail?

Trough the GUI is preferred, if not, then CMI.

Comment: Are you saying that this API call does not appear in CloudTrail? Or are you asking to see the output of the command? Please tell us more.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to reproduce this in order to get this event in cloudtrail. So far, I'm only getting "
An error occurred fetching key pair data: You are not authorized to perform this operation." without an encoded authorization failure message.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Give EC2 readonly to a user and try to stop an EC2 instance.